# How to force OpenMPI to use GCC instead of ICC? Is recompiling OpenMPI necessary?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, icc, openmpi

I have a C-code for parallel computing written for `gcc`, and I want to compile it on a cluster, which apparently uses `icc` via `mpicc`. Correcting the code to be `icc`-friendly seems to be too time-demanding, so I wonder if I can ask `OpenMPI` to use `gcc` instead. I don't have the admin rights on that cluster, and I would actually prefer to do not mess the original configuration.

If it is not possible to set in e.g. `Makefile`, then I could hopefully compile `OpenMPI` in my home directory, but I need some guidance in what must be done after that. Could you help me?

---

**UPDATE1**

The `Makefile` contains

```
CC = mpicc
CFLAGS += -DMPI
```

And here are some OpenMPI files

```
$ which mpicc
/usr/bin/mpicc

lrwxr-xr-x  /usr/bin/mpicc -> opal_wrapper
-rwxr-xr-x  /usr/bin/opal_wrapper
```

Let me know, if I can provide you more information.

---

**UPDATE2**

With the [help of Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353119/how-to-force-openmpi-to-use-gcc-instead-of-icc-is-recompiling-openmpi-necessary/3353941#3353941), I was able to find `OpenMPI` settings for `mpicc`

```
$ more /usr/local/share/openmpi/mpicc-wrapper-data.txt 
project=Open MPI
project_short=OMPI
version=1.1.4
language=C
compiler_env=CC
compiler_flags_env=CFLAGS
compiler=icc
extra_includes= openmpi
preprocessor_flags= 
compiler_flags=-pthread 
linker_flags=    
libs=-lmpi -lorte -lopal   -ldl   -Wl,--export-dynamic -lnsl -lutil -ldl 
required_file=
```

However, I do not have rights to edit this file, and `OPMI_CC = gcc` doesn't change compiler.

---

**UPDATE3**

Environmental variable `CC = gcc` doesn't help

```
$ export CC=gcc
$ echo $CC
gcc
$ make clean $$ make
...icc:...errors
```

---

**UPDATE4**

...but `export OMPI_CC=gcc` does finally help ([thanks to sharth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353119/how-to-force-openmpi-to-use-gcc-instead-of-icc-is-recompiling-openmpi-necessary/3353285#3353285)). I should one day remember that these are different things...

Despite that the binary was created, I got the following bye-bye message

```
/opt/intel/fce/9.1.036/lib/libimf.so: warning: warning: feupdateenv is not implemented and will always fail
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps#override-wrappers-after-v1.0.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the environmental variable CC to gcc.

```
csh:  setenv CC gcc
bash: export CC=gcc
```

Comment: `Makefile` has `CC = mpicc` and `CFLAGS += -DMPI`. Otherwise, I do not get `mpi` interface. Is it correct?

Comment: @Andrei: Those aren't environmental variables. You want those as well as setting the environmental variables I suggested above.

Comment: OK, I see my mistake. I have just tried as you suggest, and it is still `icc`. May be you can have a look at the page suggested by Jeff? Do I do as it says?

Comment: Bingo, now it works. You helped me to realize that `OMPI_CC` should be set outside `Makefile`

Comment: @Andrei: At the time I changed the answer, you had given the checkmark to my answer. If I was going to have the "right answer here" mark, then I figured it should at least be the right answer.

Comment: @sharth: Yes, I understand your responsibility (sorry, if I was pushing you), but not the way you do corrections. Do you see what I mean?