# How to pass -libm to MPICC? libimf.so: warning: feupdateenv is not implemented and will always fail

Tags: c, gcc, linker, openmpi

I am a newbie who tries to compile a program via `mpicc` replacing `icc` with `gcc`. I have [already discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353119/how-to-force-openmpi-to-use-gcc-instead-of-icc-is-recompiling-openmpi-necessary), that I need to use the following command to compile

```
$ OMPI_CC=gcc make
```

However, I get the following error message ([which is well-known](https://wiki.hpcc.msu.edu/display/Issues/feupdateenv+is+not+implemented+and+will+always+fail))

```
/opt/intel/fce/9.1.036/lib/libimf.so: warning: warning: feupdateenv is not implemented and will always fail
```

I try to do

```
$ make clean && OMPI_CC=gcc OMPI_LDFLAGS=-libm make
```

Then I see

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, I find the file there

```
lrwxrwxrwx /usr/lib/libm.so -> /lib/libm.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx /lib/libm.so.6 -> libm-2.3.6.so
-rw-r--r-- /lib/libm-2.3.6.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ make clean
$ OMPI_CC=gcc OMPI_LDFLAGS=-lm make
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't change anything. To be honest this error message is probably not so bad thing, since the program works fine (so far). I was just wondering how to solve this problem in case if it would do something bad.

Comment: So you got the error cannot find -lm? That's weird. Also try OMPI_LIBS.

Comment: Nono, the original warning message about `feupdateenv` persists. I suppose `lm` has been found.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--showme` flag to determine the flags used by mpicc/mpi compiler wrappers. Then invoke your own compiler of choice (icc/gcc/pgcc/whatever) and add the relevant flags so the correct MPI libraries are linked.

Remember, you need to use `--showme` with a file for the wrapper to show the correct flags.

More info is here: http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps#wrapper-showme-with-no-file